# Create ActionBar and options menu in same activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to show same menu options both in the ActionBar and in the menu options but it shows up only in one of them, is there a simple way to do it?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity" >

<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Now the items appear in the action bar.
Changing the app:showAsAction to android:app:showAsAction shows the menu items at the options menu only, any way to make them appear in both menus?

Thanks

Comment: I think the element will display in either of the two but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Change `showAsAction="always"` to `showAsAction="never"` for which you want to display in option menu at bottom...

See `showAsAction` element in below link for more details...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: Changed it, it's displayed in the option menu but now it's not in the ActionBar...

Comment: do you want to show same menu item in both action bar & option menu ?.... keep `showAsAction="always"` for menu items that you want to show in action bar.... & `showAsAction="never"` for menu items that you want to show in option menu at bottom....

Comment: Yeah, I want the same item to be seen in both menus.

Comment: For that i think you have to create two menu items with different id but same title & icon.... one with `showAsAction="always"` & other with `showAsAction="never"`... and on it's click event you can do same thing for both...